# CSS scroll animation does not show all text

Tags: html, css, css-animations, infinite-scroll, keyframe

I am trying to display a long scrolling list of sponsors, but it starts over before showing all the text.  I tried it with a defined "&-n-b-s-p-;" and without it (regular space bar).

I am using WordPress with Beaver Builder and this is an HTML code block. I tried the Text block, but have the same issue.

I looked at [Unable to scroll all text using animation in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60654056/unable-to-scroll-all-text-using-animation-in-css), but I already have white-space:nowrap.

```css
.scroll-slow p {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  white-space: pre !important;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  /* Starting position */
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Apply animation to this element */
  -moz-animation: scroll-slow 30s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: scroll-slow 30s linear infinite;
  animation: scroll-slow 30s linear infinite;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Move it (define the animation) */
@-moz-keyframes scroll-slow {
 0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scroll-slow {
 0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
 /* Browser bug fix */
@keyframes scroll-slow {
 0%   { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
 -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
 transform: translateX(100%);       
 }
 100% { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); 
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
 transform: translateX(-100%); 
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-slow">
<p>Alignment Specialists&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;CARCON Industries/STL Engineers&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;CNB&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Diamondback Energy&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Endeavor Energy Resources&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Hanna Lawfirm&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;HNB Mortgage&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Home Instead&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Jackson Hewitt&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|     Lone Star Abstract and Title Co. INC&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Malhotra Law Firm&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Midland College (BOT)&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Midland Development Corporations&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Oncor&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Premier Energy Services&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Pristine Organic Cleaners&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Sewell Family of Companies&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Southwest 66 Credit Union&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Taco diVino&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Tex-Con Management, Inc.&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;The Corrales Law Firm, PC&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Western Abstract & Title Co.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS animate scrolling text using text-indent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789222/css-animate-scrolling-text-using-text-indent)